# Update rows if data exists with executemany

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, upsert, executemany

I have the following SQL that aims to create a new record in the DB or update an existing one.

```py
sql = """INSERT INTO table (v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
         ON CONFLICT(v5) DO UPDATE
         SET v1 = ?, v3 = ?, v6 = ?
"""

self.curr.execute(sql,(
    v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6,
   # below are the values for eventual update 
    v1, v3, v6)
)
```

This works great, however, I am trying to implement batch creation of rows with `executemany()`, and also keep `ON CONFLICT` logic.

I know that it would look something similar to this:

```py
data = [
  ('Jane', date(2005, 2, 12)),
  ('Joe', date(2006, 5, 23)),
  ('John', date(2010, 10, 3)),
]
sql = """
INSERT INTO employees (first_name, hire_date) 
VALUES (%s, %s)
ON CONFLICT(first_name) DO UPDATE
SET date = %S
"""
cursor.executemany(sql, data)
```

But I am not quite sure how to pass the columns value (`hire_date`) that is used for the update if a row with `first_name` already exists

Do I pass another 3 tuples in the data array with the values for an eventual update?

I couldn't find any specific resource on the web for my need, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I ran 2nd code block and result is: 'cursor' is not defined.

Comment: you need to initialize a connection to a DB and then a cursor:
`conn = sqlite3.connect('name_of_database.db')` and then 
`curr = conn.cursor()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `EXCLUDED` table qualifier to the column name:

```
data = [
  ('Jane', date(2005, 2, 12)),
  ('Joe', date(2006, 5, 23)),
  ('John', date(2010, 10, 3)),
]
sql = """
INSERT INTO employees (first_name, hire_date) 
VALUES (?, ?)
ON CONFLICT(first_name) DO UPDATE
SET hire_date = EXCLUDED.hire_date
"""
cursor.executemany(sql, data)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I tried to find some resources regarding the `EXCLUDED` table qualifier, but I couldn't find any. Do you mind elaborating a bit on what it does under the hood?

Comment: @antpngl92 the documentation for SQLite's UPSERT is this: http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_upsert.html where it is mentioned: "...To use the value that would have been inserted had the constraint not failed, add the special "excluded." table qualifier to the column name"

Comment: Appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have three placeholders in SQL you need to bind three parameters. Therefore, repeat the date value. By the way, `sqlite3` uses the qmark, `?`, for placeholders as used in your first example and be sure to `commit`.

```py
data = [
    ('Jane', date(2005, 2, 12), date(2005, 2, 12)), 
    ('Joe', date(2006, 5, 23), date(2006, 5, 23)), 
    ('John', date(2010, 10, 3), date(2010, 10, 3)), 
] 

sql = """INSERT INTO employees (first_name, hire_date) 
         VALUES (?, ?) 
         ON CONFLICT(first_name) DO 
         UPDATE SET hire_date = ? 
      """

cursor.executemany(sql, data)
conn.commit()
```